# Setting app's time zone to current user's time zone - Time.zone vs Time.use_zone

Tags: timezone, ruby-on-rails-3.2

What's the difference between these two snippets of code? AND when should you use one vs. the other?

**Time.zone**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_time_zone

  def set_time_zone
    Time.zone = current_user.time_zone
   end
end
```

**Time.use_zone**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  around_filter :set_time_zone

  def set_time_zone(&block)
    Time.use_zone(current_user.time_zone, &block)
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `Time.use_zone` overrides `Time.zone` locally inside the supplied block and then resets `Time.zone` to existing value when it's done done.

So the second code block is the equivalent of calling `Time.zone = current_user.time_zone` at the beginning of each method and then resetting it back to the default `Time.zone` as specified in your `/config/application.rb`

Although I'm still not sure which is the recommended approach. From a performance stand point, it seems like first option would be better but there may be cases where the second option makes more sense.

More here:

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-c-use_zone
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-revised?view=asciicast